# Inverse of a function which is not one-one

Tags: functions

I found a question in a book as:

If $f: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ ($\mathbb{R}$ is the set of real numbers) defined by $f(x)=x^2+3$, then 
find $f^{-1}(7)$.

My question is:

Here $f$ is not 1-1. Then inverse of $f$ should not exist. Then why is it asked to find the inverse of $f$? Is the question incorrect or do I have some problem in understanding it properly?

Comment: I would understand it as asking for the set of all preimages of $7$ under $f$.

Comment: 'In a book' is not very specific, so I can't talk for the book, but I asume they mean the preimage, not the image. $f^{-1}(7)$ is then sloppy for $f^{-1}(\{7\})$.

Comment: @Klaus It is quite standard to write $f^{-1}(b)$ instead of $f^{-1}[\{b\})$.

Comment: @PaulFrost Standard does not mean it is not sloppy. Obviously it causes confusion to some. Obviously I was sloppy as well by writing 'image' instead of 'inverse' and now I can't edit it anymore...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, the notation $f^{-1}(7)$ *does not* mean the **number** obtained by applying the inverse of $f$ to 7; what it actually refers to is the **set**
$$f^{-1}(7) = \{x \in {\Bbb R}: f(x) = 7\}$$ (which would be, as suggested, better denoted by $f^{-1}(\{7\})$).
If $f$ is 1-1, then in particular there is one and only one element in $f^{-1}(\{7\})$, which is then given - perhaps a little confusingly - the name $f^{-1}(7)$.

Answer (score 1):

The restriction of your function to $f:[0,+\infty) \rightarrow [3,+\infty): x\mapsto x^2+3$ is bijective and for this function you can determine $f^{-1}(7)$.

Comment: But domain is $R$ (not $R^+$) , this lead me in confusion.

Comment: Here 7 lies in the domain $[0,+\infty)$ and the function $f$ is invertible on the domain.